# Facebook Graph 2.0 Global ID Vs App Scop IDs

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I just have one question concerning Facebook's shift from Global IDs to App Scope IDs:

I clearly understood how this affects the logged in user and I also read that "No matter what version they originally used to sign up for your app, the ID will remain the same for people who have already logged into your app." So no problem there, backward compatibility for existing users and new users get App Scope IDs when I shift to Graph 2.0

My question is about IDs referencing other users that might not be on my app yet, like for example name tags on pictures imported on Facebook.

So lets say a user logged into my application with V1.0, and we imported all his pictures from Facebook with all the name_tags. On the graph API each of these name_tags are identified by an ID (in this case, the global ID since I'm using V1). Now lets say I update to V2.0.

Does the backward compatibility aslo apply to name tags on pictures that were imported from Facebook , even if these name_tags could be people that are not yet on my app? Meaning, when these users join will they be identified by these original IDs?

Thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure, but most **probably not**! (you can try your app with v2.0 and see what happens). I ncase not-

You must update your app and use [`/me/taggable_friends`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/taggable_friends) API to get the taggable friends list (you'll get app-scoped ids of them) and use these ids instead.

I'm not sure if you are aware of, but you also need to [submit login review](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login) if your app is using any permission other than `public_profile`, `email` and the `user_friends` plus for `taggable_friends` before it goes live.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Sahil!

Unforunately /me/taggable_friends only returns temporary IDs that are not the real app scope ids:

Comment: This is how they describe it in the documentation: "A tagging token which can only be used in order to tag this friend, and for no other purpose. This token should not be considered a stable ID, and cannot be used to identify the friend outside the context of tagging them in stories."

Comment: I'll guess the only way for me to find out is to try it out! I will let you know as soon as I have an answer

Comment: You misread, this api is built only to accomplish what you want to do- tag friends in photo/posts. Yes these are not real ids, but it is why only they have introduced this thing so that nobody can just use the global IDs! Its not a temp ID, its an app-scope id. Your app can simply use these id for the tagging purpose- that's the only use of them. You dont need to be confused unnecessarily